# Поиск id в словаре

Tags: python-3.x

есть ответ от сервера:

```
{'response': [562, {'id': 19592}]}
```

Необходимо получить `id`

Пробовал вот так:

```
id = r['response'][0]['id']
```

И вот так:

```
id = r['response'][0]
```

Comment: `[1]` вместо `[0]` очевидно

Comment: У Вас r['response'][0] вернет 562, а ['response'][0]['id'] соответственно ошибку. Верный вариант - id = r['response'][1]['id']